# when gparted says the partition table is msdos does that mean MBR

Tags: gparted

Wikipedia says

> [T]he MBR-based partitioning scheme is in the process of being
>   superseded by the GUID Partition Table (GPT) scheme

This makes it seem that MBR and GPT are the main alternatives to each other. However, under `gparted` the create partition table function lists `gpt` and `msdos` as alternatives and there is no `mbr` in the menu. Should users assume that `gparted` has read an MBR partition table when `msdos` is displayed and that it will write an MBR partition table when `msdos` is selected when creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From [the GParted website](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php):

> This article describes how to fix some common problems that cause an
>   MSDOS partition table (also known as Master Boot Record - MBR) to be
>   invalid.

Comment: The MBR is very first sector of a drive and has the partition table in it. It started with DOS or MSDOS.  But just to keep things confused, even gpt has a protective MBR. That is just the first sector and it has one partition table entry saying drive is gpt. That is for older partition tools like fdisk before version in 16.04 and other tools that read MBR, so they know drive is partitioned and help prevent corruption.